# Is /var/run/reboot-required a reliable indicator of a needed reboot?

Tags: systemd, upgrade, reboot

After updating two Ubuntu 16.04 servers with an update that did not include the kernel, but did include packages systemd and systemd-sysv, I checked the following file:

```
ls -la /var/run/reboot-required
```

It was **not** present on one server but **was** present on the other. Not expecting this discrepancy, I did not check for the file prior to the updates. While I cannot rule out that the file may have already been there on the one server, that is unlikely as the server was rebooted two weeks ago after a kernel update and that was the last time any updates were done.

Is there a more reliable way to know which packages require a reboot and/or when the server needs to be rebooted, especially on distros like Arch?

As a general rule, do I need to reboot when upgrading systemd?

In case it helps, for upgrading ubuntu, I use this command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For upgrading Arch, I follow a few more steps, but the basic command is simply:

```
pacman -Syu
pacman -Qtdq
```

Comment: Doesn't systemd have `systemctl daemon-reexec` for this?

Comment: Maybe that's what I need. I had dismissed it when I read on the man page, " This command is of little use..." That's when I stopped reading. It's an unfortunate choice of wording for a man page. ;-)

Comment: Pity, because that sentence continues with "except ... package upgrades."